# creating a dynamic list of unique values from a drop-down box selection in excel 2016

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

ive been trying for a few hours but no luck. My aim is to auto populate cells E7 to E20 with the unique task lines for the selected project which is selected via the dropdown box (CELL E2).

Here's a picture:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in E7 and copy down.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C:C,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($A$2:$A$26)/($A$2:$A$26 = $E$2),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you for the very quick response, however it populates 1.1.1 in every cell (E7 to E20). it should populate unique Task Lines. so if i select 'Project 2' from the dropdown it should display 1.1.1
1.2.1
1.1.3
1.1.4
1.1.5

Comment: I edited the formula it should end with `ROW(1:1)))`  Make sure you are dragging the formula down.  This will force the `ROW(1:1)` to become `ROW(2:2)` and so on.